# Limited quantity items in shopping cart. How to store and remove

Tags: php, mysql

Let's say I only have 50 widgets to sell. These widgets are a limited time sale item. Once they are gone, they're gone. If someone adds one to their shopping cart, how should I temporarily decrease the quantity available and store that information until checkout is complete? What would be the best way to add that item back to the quantity available if they never checkout?

Would it be best to store the cart in a temporary database? Could I run a cron job every 20-30 minutes and delete any carts that haven't been completed?

Comment: Your proposed solution is almost exactly one that I used with success in a custom cart application.  I assigned a "session" Identifier to the cart record, stored that session identifier in the user's cookies, so that their cart information was stored / available for them while they visited the site.  I updated the timestamp of the "temp cart" record with each pageview they made, to keep the record "alive" while they were actively engated.  Note that in my situation, my "temp cart" table was *separate from* the "real" cart table.

Comment: Sounds like a good way to manage it... !

Comment: That's a good tip about updating the timestamp with every pageview. I hadn't thought about that. Thanks!